# Postgresql table name or alias in SELECT and WHERE clauses without specifying column name

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1);
```

If I try to get records from `a` for which there are records in `b` (**query 1**):

```
SELECT a.id, b FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id WHERE b is NOT NULL;
```

I get:

```
 id |  b  
----+-----
  1 | (1)
```

If I try to get records from `a` for which there are NO records in `b` (**query 2**):

```
SELECT a.id, b FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id WHERE b IS NULL;
```

I get:

```
 id | b 
----+---
  2 |
```

It seems OK.

Then I alter `b`:

```
ALTER TABLE b ADD COLUMN s TEXT NULL;
```

then query 1 does not return any rows, query 2 returns the same rows and

```
SELECT a.id, b FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id;
```

returns

```
 id |  b   
----+------
  1 | (1,)
  2 |
```

My questions are:

1. Why does Postresql allow to use table name or alias in `WHERE` clause without specifying column name?
2. What is `(1,)` in column `b` of resulting rows?
3. Why does `(1,)` not satisfy `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in query 1 and query 2?

**P.S.** If I alter table `b` as `ALTER TABLE b ADD COLUMN s TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` instead then queries 1 and 2 return the same rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering by questions:

1. This is row constructor, so every value from a column builds up a row value (composite value) using values from your columns for its member fields
2. `(1,)` is a row constructor with first member being `1` and second member (your text field) which has a `null` value, thus no value is shown.
3. You're comparing entire row constructor which actually satisfies both of comparison (is null and is not null)

**More on point 3:**

```
select *, b is not null as b_not_null, b is null as b_null from b;
```

Reult:

```
 id | b_not_null | b_null
----+------------+--------
  1 | t          | f
```

A row `IS NULL` when all of its members have `NULL` values, otherwise it `IS NOT NULL`. Reproduce:

```
create table rowtest ( col1 int, col2 int);
insert into rowtest values (null,null), (1,1), (null,1);

select 
  col1, col2, rowtest,
  case when rowtest is null then true else false end as rowtest_null
from rowtest;
```

Result:

```
 col1 | col2 | rowtest | rowtest_null
------+------+---------+--------------
      |      | (,)     | t
    1 |    1 | (1,1)   | f
      |    1 | (,1)    | f
```

---

Actually, for your queries they both could be rewritten to:

**Query1**: Get records from `a` with matching records from `b`

Using `INNER JOIN` which actually is the same as `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id, b FROM a JOIN b on a.id = b.id;
```

**Query2**: Get records from `a` with no matching records from `b`

Using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM b
  WHERE a.id = b.id
  );
```

For the last query if you really need the second empty column you can add a static value to select list like that:

```
SELECT a.id, null as b
```

Comment: Thanks for the term `row constructor`. I missed it when I tried to search the answer. Please in answer to question 3 add description how rows are tested for `IS NULL` (all values of row have to be `NULL`) and `IS NOT NULL` (all values of row have to be `NOT NULL`). May be it useful for others to add an example for table with two columns three rows where the first row has all null values, the second row has not null in first column and null in second column and third row has not nulls in both columns.

Comment: Answer edited to include steps to reproduce and observe the behaviour of comparing a row to `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: A row IS NULL when all of its members have NULL values, otherwise it IS NOT NULL - that's wrong. Actually the row `IS NOT NULL` only when all of its members have not null values.

Answer (score 0):

The table name can be used in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` to refer to a record value containing the entire row of the table. In the output of `psql` a record will appear like `(1)` (if it has one field), or `(1,2)` (if it has two fields), etc. The `(1,)` that you see is a record with two fields that contain the values `1` and `NULL`. A value of record type can be null, e.g. in a left join if there is no matching row for the second table.